# Get custom event from webchat BOT Framework 4 using ActivityPrompt

Tags: c#, botframework

I implemented the abstract class ActivityPrompt to wait for a custom event inside a waterfall dialog, the implementation of the class is this:

```
public class EventActivityPrompt : ActivityPrompt
{
    public EventActivityPrompt(string dialogId, PromptValidator<Activity> validator) : base(dialogId, validator)
    {
    }
}
```

I am using in a waterfall dialog:

```
AddDialog(new EventActivityPrompt(LoginSucessActivityPrompt, _validator));

var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text("Wait for login", "", InputHints.IgnoringInput);
return await stepContext.PromptAsync(LoginSucessActivityPrompt, new PromptOptions { Prompt = promptMessage }, cancellationToken);

async Task<bool> _validator(PromptValidatorContext<Activity> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var activity = promptContext.Recognized.Value;

            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event && activity.Name == "LOGIN_SUCCESS")
            {
                promptContext.Recognized.Value = MessageFactory.Text("login sucess:" + activity.Value.ToString());
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                await promptContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("Please send an 'event'-type Activity with a value of xxx.");
            }
            return false;
        }
```

from the webchat I am sending this:

```
setTimeout(() => store.dispatch({
      type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
      payload: { name: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', value: { userid: '123456789', session: '123456' }, text: 'done.' }
  }), 3000);
```

This solution works but not with events sent by the direct line webchat, I received the event on the OnTurnAsync but not in the validator, I am sending this from the webchat. Please any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your validator is not being hit when you send the event is because the `WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT` dispatch payload does not utilize a `text` property (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/core/src/actions/sendEvent.js)). So, despite your including the `text` property in your payload, by the time it reaches your bot it has been ignored/stripped out, as seen here:

```js
store.dispatch( {
  type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
  payload: {
    name: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
    value: {
      name: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
      value: {
        userid: '123456789',
        session: '123456'
      }
    },
    text: 'yes'
  }
} )
```

```js
{ type: 'event',
  id: 'EEzl4C4p6AHKfMwIuhmLTM-o|0000006',
  timestamp: 2019-12-17T20:31:46.276Z,
  serviceUrl: 'https://directline.botframework.com/',
  channelId: 'directline',
  from: { id: 'dl_123', name: 'johndoe', role: 'user' },
  conversation: { id: 'EEzl4C4p6AHKfMwIuhmLTM-o' },
  recipient: { id: 'b******@QaeuoeEamLg', name: 'D****** *****r' },
  locale: 'en-US',
  channelData:
   { clientActivityID: '15766147033627cr89fn0ns3',
     clientTimestamp: '2019-12-17T20:31:43.362Z' },
  value:
   { name: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
     value: { userid: '123456789', session: '123456' } },
  name: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS'
}
```

To fix this, you need to dispatch two actions, `WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE` and `WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT`. The first will register with the prompt and the validator. The second will be the event info. If you need the event data to be sent after validation is successful, then you can dispatch the `WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT` in response to some returned value sent by the bot upon validation. In this case, you would use `action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY'`, match on the returned value, and then send the event (example [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.b.incoming-activity-event)).

```js
store.dispatch({
  type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE',
  payload: {
    text: 'yes'
  }
} ),
store.dispatch( {
  type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
  payload: {
    name: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
    value: {
      name: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
      value: {
        userid: '123456789',
        session: '123456'
      }
    },
    text: 'yes'
  }
} )
```

Alternatively, depending on your use case, you could send your event data in the `channelData` property of a posted message activity from Web Chat. You can just as easily filter on this as on any event and reduces the work load to just one action. In the below example, I'm matching on text input for simplicity.

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/simple-update-in/dist/simple-update-in.production.min.js"></script>

if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY') {
  if(action.payload.activity && action.payload.activity.text) {
    let text = action.payload.activity.text.toLowerCase();
    if(text === 'logged in') {
      const userid = 'xyz789';
      const session = '123456';
      action = window.simpleUpdateIn(
        action,
        ['payload', 'activity', 'channelData'],
        () => ({
          'userId': userid,
          'userDetails': session
        })
      )
    } 
  }
}
```

Hope of help!