# Microsoft Botframework Send Proactive Message to Bot (and not to the User)

Tags: c#, botframework

we are currently developing some automation with the botframework.

At some point in the conversation, we sent some data through a service bus for processing and wait for a response and then want to continue with the conversation. We already implemented the part where we wait for an response entry in the service bus subscription and then we want to send an Activity from type Event to the bot.

We did the same steps with the proactive message as described in other posts.
We are able to recreate the botclient and conversation reference and all, but in the end when we send the activity, we always send it to the user and not to the bot. But this doesn't trigger the "[EventActivityPrompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59339889/get-custom-event-from-webchat-bot-framework-4-using-activityprompt)".

The only way where we achieved the desired outcome was when we made a post to api/messages, but this is too complicated for our taste, and we are looking for an easier way over the botClient (or similar technology)

Has anyone some good ideas? :)

ServiceBusReceiver Message Processing:

```
private static async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Process the message.
        Console.WriteLine($"Received message: SequenceNumber:{message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber} Body:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");

        _logger?.LogInformation("Received message '{id}' with label '{label}' from queue.", message.MessageId, message.Label);


        var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BotCarLicensingOrderRpaRequest>(message.Body);

        data.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("ServiceUrl", out var serviceUrl);
        data.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("ChannelId", out var channelId);
        data.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("BotId", out var botId);
        data.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("UserId", out var userId);
        data.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("ReplyToId", out var replyToId);
        var conversationReference = _offTurnConversationService.CreateSyntheticConversationReference(
            channelId?.ToString(),
            data.ConversationId,
            serviceUrl?.ToString());
        conversationReference.User = new ChannelAccount()
        {
            Id = userId?.ToString(),
            Role = "user"
        };
        conversationReference.Bot = new ChannelAccount
        {
            Id = botId?.ToString(),
            Role = "bot"
        };
        var activity = (Activity)Activity.CreateEventActivity();
        activity.Text = "success";
        activity.ChannelId = channelId?.ToString();
        activity.ServiceUrl = serviceUrl?.ToString();
        activity.RelatesTo = conversationReference;
        activity.Conversation = new ConversationAccount
        {
            Id = data.ConversationId
        };

        activity.ReplyToId = replyToId?.ToString();

        activity.ApplyConversationReference(conversationReference, true);

        // Complete the message so that it is not received again.
        // This can be done only if the subscriptionClient is created in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode (which is the default).
        await _messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
        // This "works" but is complicated, as we have to set up a whole HTTP call
        await _offTurnConversationService.SendActivityToBotAsync(activity);
        
        // This just sends the Event to the user, no matter how I set up the conversation 
        // reference regarding From/Recipient
        // And it doesn't help in continuing the conversation
        await _offTurnConversationService.SendToConversationThroughPipelineAsync(
            async (turnContext, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activity, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            },
            conversationReference);
        // Note: Use the cancellationToken passed as necessary to determine if the subscriptionClient has already been closed.
        // If subscriptionClient has already been closed, you can choose to not call CompleteAsync() or AbandonAsync() etc.
        // to avoid unnecessary exceptions.
    }
```

OffTurnConversationService:

```
public ConversationReference CreateSyntheticConversationReference(string channelId, string conversationId, string serviceUrl)
    {
        ArgumentGuard.NotNull(channelId, nameof(channelId));
        ArgumentGuard.NotNull(conversationId, nameof(conversationId));
        ArgumentGuard.NotNull(serviceUrl, nameof(serviceUrl));

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_botOptions.CurrentValue.BotId))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("A valid bot id must be configured in your bot options in order to create a synthetic conversation reference.");
        }

        // WARNING: This implementation works for directline and webchat.
        //          Changes could be necessary for other channels.
        var supportedChannels = new List<string>()
        {
            Channels.Directline,
            Channels.Webchat
        };
        if (supportedChannels.Any(c => c.Equals(channelId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        {
            _logger.LogWarning(
                "The synthetic conversation reference created for channel {UsedChannel} might not work properly, " +
                "because it's not supported and tested. Supported channels are {SupportedChannel}.",
                channelId,
                string.Join(",", supportedChannels));
        }

        var conversationReference = new ConversationReference()
        {
            Conversation = new ConversationAccount()
            {
                Id = conversationId
            },
            Bot = new ChannelAccount()
            {
                Id = _botOptions.CurrentValue.BotId,
                Name = _botOptions.CurrentValue.BotId
            },
            ChannelId = channelId,
            ServiceUrl = serviceUrl
        };

        return conversationReference;
    }

public virtual async Task SendActivityToBotAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        // Create the new request to POST to the client
        var forwardRequest = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(_botOptions.CurrentValue.ReplyServiceUrl),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        };

        // Change the host for the request to be the forwarding URL.
        forwardRequest.Headers.Host = forwardRequest.RequestUri.Host;

        // If the child bot is not running on local mode (no app-id/password), 
        // we're going send an authentication header.
        OAuthResponse authToken = await GetTokenAsync(_botOptions.CurrentValue.MicrosoftAppId, _botOptions.CurrentValue.MicrosoftAppPassword);
        forwardRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken.AccessToken);

        // Altered activity to JSON content
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        forwardRequest.Content = content;

        using var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(forwardRequest);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string message = $"Failed to send activity '{activity.Id}' to client bot. {response.ReasonPhrase}";
            throw new Exception(message);
        }
    }
public virtual async Task SendToConversationThroughPipelineAsync(
        BotCallbackHandler callback,
        ConversationReference conversationReference)
    {
        ArgumentGuard.NotNull(callback, nameof(callback));
        ArgumentGuard.NotNull(conversationReference, nameof(conversationReference));

        // Avoiding 401 "Unauthorized" errors
        TrustServiceUrl(conversationReference.ServiceUrl);

        // Reuse adapter with its pipeline to send responses back to the user (like pro-active messages)
        await ((BotAdapter)_botFrameworkHttpAdapter).ContinueConversationAsync(
            _botOptions.CurrentValue.MicrosoftAppId,
            conversationReference,
            callback,
            default);
    }
```

Comment: It would be difficult to answer your question without the code. Please, provide the example of what has been done so far - because, for example, nobody knows what are "steps with the proactive message as described in other posts".

Comment: I updated my post with the code and I was referring to this considering the proactive message: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: Sadly no, we went with the route of using the bot API (api/messages) instead of using the bot Client